# How to get the Expression Value out

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble with a linq expression. Here's the method of the decompiled code of `OracleDatabaseData` class where it is used.

```
public override IEnumerable<TypeRegistration> GetRegistrations()
{
    yield return new TypeRegistration<Database>(() => new OracleDatabase(this.ConnectionString,
            from opd in this.PackageMappings
            select (IOraclePackage)opd, Container.Resolved<IDataInstrumentationProvider>(this.Name)))
        {
            Name = base.Name,
            Lifetime = TypeRegistrationLifetime.Transient
        };
    yield break;
}
```

I have already set the `ConnectionString` for this class (`OracleDatabaseData` in *OracleDatabaseDataMicrosoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll*)) and it is used within this method by passing it to the `OracleDatabase` class constructor as shown in the method. What I want to do is print the `ConnectionString` that I've set, after calling this method. Is it even possible? The final expression is getting set in `LambdaExpression` property of `TypeRegistration` class in *Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll*.

It would be great if anyone give a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: If you can set the ConnectionString it should not be hard to make it accessible wherever you need it, should it? What do you mean by *The final expression is getting set in...*? It is not clear what you're aiming to do.

Comment: the method is returning IEnumerable<TypeRegistration> collection. I need to take the ConnectionString out from that returning TypeRegistration object. What I meant by the final expression is, the lamda expression that is passed inside new TypeRegistration<Database>()

Comment: What does the TypeRegistration look like? If it doesn't have a connection string, how can any divination get that info?